# libjingle compiling error

Tags: swt, scons, libjingle

When compiling libjingle, on running the 'hammer.sh' on the swtoolkit,
i get the following import error,

```
root@den-pc:~/tejesh/libjingle-0.6.14/talk# sh ../../swtoolkit/hammer.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "../../swtoolkit/wrapper.py", line 44, in <module>
import SCons.Script
ImportError: No module named SCons.Script
```

so how do i fix this import error... any suggestions?

i already setup the environment variables for scons (SCONS_DIR) and have all the libraries installed..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have SCons correctly installed, then it sounds like a problem with python not being able to find it. In addition to the SCONS_DIR environment variable, try including the SCons location in the PYTHONPATH environment variable.

Comment: yeah.. ... sorry did'nt see that voting part before :D

Comment: I don't understand this advice. Are you suggesting create a new environment variable called "PYTHONPATH" and set it to the location of the SCons installation? Who knows...

Comment: @infact "PYTHONPATH" is definitely not a new environment variable, but rather something supported by Python to look for modules. The libjingle scripts were not finding SCons, so Im suggesting a standard way to find it: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: @infact, I would appreciate a response, please. Was your down vote because you disagree with my answer? (even though my answer actually helped the OP)  If so, can you suggest a better way than using the standard PYTHONPATH variable? If not, then please remove the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

when you install scons,in the README file,you can use:

```
 # python setup.py install --standalone-lib
```

that can make scons modules into pythonpath.